# Android Gradle Build

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

```
Error:Could not find spde.build:sdl-pack:21.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sdl-pack/21.0.3/sdl-pack-21.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sdl-pack/21.0.3/sdl-pack-21.0.3.jar
Required by:
    :Module1 : unspecified
```

Android Support Library : 21.0.3 installed:

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\1.0.0

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
            String apiLevel = ((project.hasProperty('API'))?API:'21')
            if (apiLevel == '19') {
                classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0"
            } else if (apiLevel == '21.1') {
                classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+"
            } else {`enter code here`
                classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0"
            }
            classpath "spde.build:sdl-pack:" + apiLevel + ".0.3"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Need help in solving the build error.

Comment: Remove the `if/else`, use `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1"`

Comment: Changed but didn't work.

            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1"

             classpath "spde.build:sdl-pack:" + apiLevel + ".0.1"

Comment: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.1/gradle-1.0.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.1/gradle-1.0.1.jar
Required by:
    :Module1:unspecified

Comment: Do not use `apiLevel`, specify a real version for `spde.build:sdl-pack`. Please see my answer below to ensure you have everything downloaded.

Comment: not the android tooling is the problem here - spde.build:sdl-pack is not found - and I also do not see this on jcenter or maven-central - perhaps it is some local thing that has to be deployed first

Answer (score 0):

Read this post:

- https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.htm

There are no `21.0.3` version. Maximum version is `21.1.1`.

Comment: String apiLevel = ((project.hasProperty('API'))?API:'21')
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0"
            classpath "spde.build:sdl-pack:" + apiLevel + ".0.0"
Error:Could not find spde.build:sdl-pack:21.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sdl-pack/21.0.0/sdl-pack-21.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sdl-pack/21.0.0/sdl-pack-21.0.0.jar
Required by:
    :Module1:unspecified

Answer (score 0):

Go into your SDK Manager and make sure you have the following installed(download latest):

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Repository

[image: sdk manager 1]
[image: sdk manager 2]